# play framework passing sub class to scala template

Tags: scala, templates, frameworks, playframework-2.2

Hey I am trying to create form from sub class:

```
models.Incident.report
```

looks something like that:

```
public class Incidet{
  public class Report{
  }
}
```

I am passing to scala template

```
Form<Incident.Report> filled_form = form(Incident.Report.class).bindFromRequest();
return ok(filterForm.render());
```

And in scala template parametr is:

```
@(filtrForm: Form[models.Incident.Report])
```

I am getting an error:

```
Compilation error
type Report is not a member of object models.Incident
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, nested classes are addressed using `#` operator. So correct syntax is:

```
@(filtrForm: Form[models.Incident#Report])
```

Comment: thanks. it helps. Now I need to create a constructor for inner class.